# How to update layout child views in recycler view in runtime

Tags: android

There is my adapter class

```
public class AlbumAdapterDemo extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumAdapterDemo.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private AlbumModel mAlbumModel;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
private List<ViewHolder> mViewHolders = new ArrayList<>();
Handler handler;
File dir;

public AlbumAdapterDemo(Context context, AlbumModel albumModel, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    mAlbumModel = albumModel;
    this.mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    dir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "audio");
    boolean isDirectoryCreated = dir.exists();
    if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
        isDirectoryCreated = dir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (isDirectoryCreated) {
        // do something
        Log.d("mkdirs option", "Directory already exists.");
    }
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {
    mAlbumModel.getAudios().remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_album, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    mViewHolders.add(viewHolder);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Audio audio = getItem(position);

    if (holder.tvAlbumTitle != null) {
        assert audio != null;
        holder.tvAlbumTitle.setText(audio.getTrackName().replace(".mp3", "").replace("_", " "));
    }
    if (holder.audioSize != null) {
        assert audio != null;
        holder.audioSize.setText(audio.getTrackSize());
    }

    if (Utils.checkFileExist(dir.getPath() + "/" + mAlbumModel.getAudios().get(position).getTrackName())) {
        if (holder.btnDownload != null) {
            holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (holder.btnDelete != null) {
            holder.btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        if (holder.btnDelete != null) {
            holder.btnDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (holder.btnDownload != null) {
            holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mAlbumModel.getAudios().size();
}

private Audio getItem(int position) {
    if (position >= 0 && position < mAlbumModel.getAudios().size()) {
        return mAlbumModel.getAudios().get(position);
    }
    return null;
}

public void onEvent(AudioEvent event) {

    switch (event.getType()) {

        case STOP:
            for (ViewHolder vh : mViewHolders) {
                if (vh != null) {
                    Audio audio = getItem(vh.getAdapterPosition());
                    if (audio != null && audio.getTrackId() == (event.getAudio().getTrackId())
                            && audio.getTrackName().equals(event.getAudio().getTrackName())) {
                        vh.closeSeekBar(true);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @Nullable
    @Bind(R.id.rl_item_album)
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Bind(R.id.tv_item_album)
    TextView tvAlbumTitle;

    @Nullable
    @Bind(R.id.btn_delete)
    ImageButton btnDelete;

    @Nullable
    @Bind(R.id.btn_download)
    ImageButton btnDownload;

    @Nullable
    @Bind(R.id.audioSize)
    TextView audioSize;

    @Nullable
    @Bind(R.id.progressBar)
    SeekBar mProgressBar;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        try {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.rl_item_album)
    void clickItem() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PlayActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("category", mAlbumModel.getCategory());
        intent.putExtra("url", mAlbumModel.getCategory() + "/" + mAlbumModel.getAlbum() + "/" + mAlbumModel.getAudios().get(getAdapterPosition()).getTrackName());
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.btn_download, R.id.btn_delete})
    void options(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_delete:
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onDeleteListener(mAlbumModel, getAdapterPosition());
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btn_download:
                mOnItemClickListener.onDownloadListener(mAlbumModel, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
        }
    }


    public void closeSeekBar(boolean isSeekBar) {
        if (isSeekBar) {

            if (btnDownload != null) {
                btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (btnDelete != null) {
                btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}

 public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onDeleteListener(AlbumModel model, int position);

    void onDownloadListener(AlbumModel model, int position);
 }
}
```

I would like to update view when file is downloaded.
There is my service class

```
public class DownloadHelper extends Service {

DownloadManager downloadManager;
File dir;
private Audio mAudio;
private HashMap<Long, Audio> specialFeedItem;
Gson mGson;
private int counter = 0;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    specialFeedItem = new HashMap<>();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {

    if (intent != null) {
        mGson = new Gson();
        String filePath = intent.getStringExtra("file_path");
        String fileName = intent.getStringExtra("file_name");
        String audio = intent.getStringExtra("audio");
        Type type = new TypeToken<Audio>() {
        }.getType();
        mAudio = mGson.fromJson(audio, type);
        dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "audio");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }

        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri download_uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(download_uri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
        request.setDescription(mAudio.getTrackName());
        request.setTitle("test");
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, dir.getName(), fileName);
        final long enqueue = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        specialFeedItem.put(enqueue, mAudio);
        specialFeedItem.get(enqueue).setDownloaded(false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    boolean downloading = true;

                    while (downloading) {

                        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                        q.setFilterById(enqueue);

                        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                                downloading = false;
                                if (specialFeedItem.get(enqueue) != null) {
                                    Audio audio1 = specialFeedItem.get(enqueue);
                                    specialFeedItem.get(enqueue).setDownloaded(true);
                                    EventBus.getDefault().post(AudioEvent.stop(audio1));
 //Toast.makeText(DownloadHelper.this, audio1.getTrackName() + " yuklandi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    counter++;
                                }

                            } else {
                                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED) {
//Utils.showToast(DownloadHelper.this, "Yuklashda xatolik bo'ldi?");
                                }
                            }
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (specialFeedItem.size() == counter) {
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(AudioEvent.update());
                        Log.d("Service ", " is done his job ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

So How can I update my view at runtime in recyclerView. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please can someone help me It is really important

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Before doing it, you need to set new list to your adapter. :)